# What is actual ways Nginx purge cache with wildcard HTTP request?

Tags: nginx, caching, lua, webserver, cache-control

First of all I searching and trying some articles:

**1)** https://www.ryadel.com/en/nginx-purge-proxy-cache-delete-invalidate-linux-centos-7/

In the first way:

a) update cache by curl request (BYPASS), it works for me, but there is no example for updating cache by wildcard

b) deleting the cache by curl request with the PURGE method, using the outdated module ngx_cache_purge-2.3, but there is no example for updating the cache on the wildcard, and at least configured as shown in the article does not work for me (nginx 1.14):

> curl -X PURGE -I mysite.com/text.txt
>
> curl: (52) Empty reply from server

**2)** https://scene-si.org/2016/11/02/purging-cached-items-from-nginx-with-lua/;
https://gist.github.com/titpetric/2f142e89eaa0f36ba4e4383b16d61474/revisions

In the second way:

If I understand correctly, lua requires nginx version 1.10, and mine is v1.14 and there is no lua module for v.1.14.

> nginx: [emerg] module "/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_http_lua_module.so" version 1010001 instead of 1014000 in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1

**So my question is:** is there working way for **Nginx v1.14** purge cache **with wildcard** HTTP request that You can advice?

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is a bit old. But I am currently using this lua module, which allows wildcard: https://github.com/diego-treitos/nginx_cache_multipurge

It has all the instructions to install it and use it.

Answer (score -2):

You should add PURGE as follows then the problem would be solved.

```
if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST|PURGE)$ ) {
        return 444;
}
```